# SSRS - Repeat formatting on first row of each page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

The requirement received for report in SSRS includes repeating formatting for the first row for 1 column on each page.

I already have Column Headers repeating on each page. This requirement is to repeat formatting of first data row (below column header) on each page.

Example:

```
Name   Money
ABC     $100
DEF      200
```

now Page 2 should look like

```
Name   Money
ABCD     $10
PQRS   10000
```

The $ sign should appear for first row of each page.

I was able to look at `RowNumber()` and do the format for first row

```
IIF(RowNumber("Table 1") = 1, "$" + Fields!Data.Value, Fields!Data.Value)
```

The first page has less number of rows than other pages, because it has a sub report taking up approximate half the page. So returning a fixed number of rows per page was not an option.

I am using SSRS 2008R2. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: if you setup a fixed number of rows per page it should be easy to add the $ on the correct row. otherwise. not that easy. But you might be able to detect page change with custom code, not sure about last statement. Why not just add the symbol to the header?

Comment: The requirement asks for symbol to the first detail row of each page. That is the reason, we are not adding a symbol to the header. I tried to use the PageNumber in the expression builder, but it is only allowed for Header and Footer. Do you have a link for how to detect a row is the first detail row on a page (by using custom code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true you can only access Global!PageNumber on Header or Footer.

Input this code in Report Properties code:

```
dim c as integer = 1 
dim last_c as integer = 0

public function SetCurrentPage(i as integer) 
 c = i 
 return c 
end function

public function PageValue()

if c <> last_c then     
 last_c = c     
 return "$" 
else
 return "" 
end if 
end function
```

On the header of your report insert a Textbox with the following expression:

```
= code.SetCurrentPage(Globals!PageNumber)
```

This way you can save you currentpage on the code behind.

On the cell you want to add the "$" concatenate with

```
=code.PageValue()
```

Should only return $ on the first call for each page change.

Hope it is a good example

Comment: It worked flawlessly in every example i tested it in. Good luck